# when using $compile why do images take a long time to load?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm using a directive that looks like this to inject some html into an angular page:

```
.directive("injected", ['$compile', 'toolsService' , ($compile, toolsService, type) -> 
    scope: true
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      type = attrs.widgetType
      attrs.$observe "template", (template) ->
        if angular.isDefined(template) and !!template
          # compile the provided template against the current scope
          el = $compile(template)(scope)
          # stupid way of emptying the element
          element.html ""
          # add the template content
          element.append el
```

It's working fine but the problem is that an image inside the compiled html (that is there to indicate that the app is still calculating the values that go inside that portion of the page)  is loading way way way late in the page lifecycle.

If the html looks like this:

```
<!-- outside the compiled html -->
<img src="img/yellow-refresh-2.gif">

<!-- the compiled html -->
<div ng-init="data.refreshing = true; data.error = false;">
  <div>{{data.refreshing}}</div>
  <div class="header">
    <h5 class="ib alias ng-binding">This is the title</h5>
    <div class="dataStatus ib right">
      <img ng-hide="data.refreshing == false" src="img/yellow-refresh-2.gif" class="ind refresh ng-hide">
      <img ng-hide="data.refreshing || data.error" class="ind good">
      <img ng-show="data.error" class="ind error ng-hide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The img outside the compiled html will be visible immediately but the same img with the same source inside the compiled html is visible about a full second later. In fact my code can ask the database to do aggregation on a reasonably large record set and display those results (inside the compiled html) *before* the image inside the compiled html is visible.

`{{data.refreshing}}` is visible on the page and is true when the page loads. I can see it switch to false when the data comes back from the db call. The html (`{{data.refreshing}}` especially) is visible quite quickly after the template compile is called while the images next to it show up nearly half a second later -- but the same image at the top of the page is visible right when the page loads.

Important note: this is much much more likely to be a problem if this is the first page load (Ctrl F5). But it can't just be a loading problem because the img outside the compiled html is visible right away in all instances.

How do I get the image inside the compiled html to show up sooner? It needs to be visible as soon as the compiled html is... well, compiled.

Comment: It's probably not the image loading, it probably has something to do with `data.refreshing`. I would guess that this value is not initialized to the value you think it is until something else, that takes a full second, is done. I can't see any code here which tells us where data comes from. Try just outputting `{{data.refreshing}}` to see what it shows.. maybe it's evaluating to the String "false" which actually evaluates to true.

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't mention that I tried that. Will update.

Comment: `throw 'no compile service' unless $compile?` -> Is it real?

Comment: @IlanFrumer is that relevant? I must have put it in there to debug a problem loading the compile service. I'll remove it.

Comment: @jcollum not directly, If you are inside a directive so there must be a $compile service. How can someone use this directive without having a compile service available after it's already been injected?

Comment: OK I built this code months ago, I have no idea why I put that line in and I don't see why it's relevant so let's just let it go.

Comment: Actually now I remember why that code is there: because I put checks like that in all over my code. I'd rather not assume that something will be present, so I check to make sure that it really is there if I need it. If it isn't, `throw`. Makes for a meaningful and easy to understand error.

Comment: Where's a plunker/fiddle with minimal implementation showing the issue?

Comment: It seems like your template should be compiled before your link function.  Can you just put a template member in your directive so it gets automatically compiled instead of waiting for the link to be called?

Comment: @GeoffGenz but then wouldn't I need to know what the html looks like ahead of time? The point of the template is to load variable html based on what's in the directive. Maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: @Beyers I'll make a plunkr if no one sees the problem right away.

Comment: Seems like you're describing a simple ng-include directive.  I'd have to player with the code, but it just feels wrong to compile in the link function.  Compile just produces html, and something else has to happen before it's injected into the page, which is probably why you're seeing a delay.